# SQL decrements multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data base containing boxes with products. I have a table containing associations between boxes and product :

```
- GUIDParent : GUID of the product
- GUIDChild : GUID of the box
- DateDelete : if set association has been deleted
- Order : index of product in box
```

I created a stored procedure to remove association (set DateDelete to now). But How can I write a command to update order in table ?

Example :

```
- Product0  |  Box1  |  NULL  | 0
- Product1  |  Box1  |  NULL  | 1
- Product2  |  Box1  |  NULL  | 2
- Product3  |  Box1  |  NULL  | 3
- Product4  |  Box1  |  NULL  | 4
```

Remove Product2 :

```
- Product0  |  Box1  |     NULL     | 0
- Product1  |  Box1  |     NULL     | 1
- Product2  |  Box1  |  22/11/2017  | 2 (Or NULL ?)
- Product3  |  Box1  |     NULL     | 2
- Product4  |  Box1  |     NULL     | 3
```

I actually have (simplified version) :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [deleteLink]
    @guidParent uniqueidentifier,
    @guidChild uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION 

        UPDATE ASSOTABLE SET DateDelete=GETDATE(),DateUpDate=GETUTCDATE()
        WHERE GUIDParent = @guidParent AND GUIDChild = @guidChild

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    RETURN 0;

END
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problems did you encounter?

Have you tried  `UPDATE ASSOTABLE SET DateDelete=GETDATE(),DateUpDate=GETUTCDATE(),order=null`?
Seems to me that should work...

Comment: @Sander The problem is not to set Product2.Order to NULL, but to decrements Product3 and 4 order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I understand your question a bit better, I think you'd need to update all the rows with [order] above the order of the 'deleted' row.

So you can set a variable of the [order] that you're going to delete like so:

```
declare @deletedOrder INT
set @deletedOrder = select [order] from ASSOTABLE 
    WHERE GUIDParent = @guidParent AND GUIDChild = @guidChild

update ASSOTABLE
set [order] = [order]-1
where [order] > @deletedOrder
```

This way, all the orders that are greater than the order you deleted, will get decremented by 1.

By the way: Since 'order' is a very common term in SQL, I'd suggest not using it as a columnname. Otherwise you'd end up with queries that contain phrases like 'order by order', which can be confusing or even lead to errors. Personally, I'd use 'sequence'.

Comment: Works good, thank you. Don't worry about the names, I use others terms 'order', 'DateDelete' etc are just for the example.